# Adding categories between items in AutoCompleteTextView Android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want an `AutoCompleteTextView` which shows the Main cities and the sub cities.
Only a sub city can be clicked where a main city is shown as a title/category.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean one item in the autocomplete will have Main city and subcity. If yes then you can attach the click listener on the sub city inside your adapter.

Comment: im searching to do the same, did you find a way ?